# Solve recurrence formula

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms

Thanks! That helps a lot. I think the substituting is the way to go

Comment: I'd try checking the first several terms, possibly using a spreadsheet to organize my calculations.  The first difficulty I run into is not knowing what to do for $T(3)$, since the basis at $T(1)$ doesn't seem to determine anything except $T(2^n)$ for $n \ge 0$.

Comment: @hardmath: my solution offers a way out, I think, unless there is something else going on at non-powers-of-two.

Comment: @hardmath:  you are correct, though sometimes the division is integer division to solve that.  But for starters, I would just solve it for $n$ a power of $2$.  Often it helps then to set $n=2k$ and rewrite it as a function of $k$.

Answer (score 1):

I have an interesting way to get to the answer, which I believe is

$$T(n) = \frac{2^{2 n}}{4 n 3^n}$$

for $n \ge 1$.  Let $n=2^k$.  Then define $U_k=T(2^k)$.  You get the recursion

$$U_k=2^k U_{k-1}^2$$

$$U_0=1/3$$

By some playing around and induction, I got the following solution:

$$U_k = \frac{2^{f(k)}}{3^{2^k}}$$

where

$$f(k) = \sum_{m=1}^k (k-m+1)2^{m-1} = 2^{k+1}-(k+2)$$

How did I get this?  I played around with the first few terms and established a pattern:

$$U_0=\frac{1}{3}$$
$$U_1 = \frac{2^1}{3^2}$$
$$U_2 = \frac{2^{2+2\cdot 1}}{3^4}$$
$$U_3 = \frac{2^{3+(2\cdot(2+2\cdot1))}}{3^8}$$

Carry on forming the exponent in the numerator, and you will see how I got $f(k)$.  The stated result follows, because you can rewrite this expression for $U$ as

$$U_k = \frac{\left(2^{2^k} \right )^2}{4 \cdot 2^k 3^{2^k}} = T(2^k)$$

Plug $n=2^k$ and you get the above expression.

Comment: $U(0)=1/3$; see the initial condition.

Comment: Somehow I misread it.  Sorry

Comment: Changing from $n$ to $k$ when the series is only defined for $n=2^k$ is often useful.

Comment: One more reason to believe it is the right formula. I found the same by a different method.

Comment: @julien: cool, always nice to see that.  BTW welcome to the 10k club!

Comment: Thanks. I got myself a burger to celebrate.

Comment: I read about a burger in a Las Vegas restaurant that has 10k calories.  Perhaps you did that?

Comment: That would have been very appropriate indeed. With fries and drink, I believe I only managed to reach 1K calories.

Answer (score 1):

There is a linear recurrence formula hidden not far.

By the change of varibale $n=2^k$ and setting $x_k:=T(2^k)$, the problem amounts to solving
$$
x_k=2^kx_{k-1}^2\qquad x_0=\frac{1}{3}.
$$
Of course, $x_k>0$ for all $k$ by induction, so we consider the sequence $y_k=\log_2x_k$, which satisfies
$$
y_k=2y_{k-1}+k\qquad y_0=-\log_23.
$$
The general solution of the homogeneous part is $C2^k$. And by the method of undetermined coefficients, we look for a particular solution of the form $y_k=Ak+B$. Plugging this is the reccurrence formula yields $A=-1$ and $B=-2$.
So the general solution is:
$$
y_k=C2^k-k-2.
$$
Given $y_0=C-2=-\log_23$, we get
$$
y_k=(2-\log_23)2^k-k-2
$$
hence
$$
x_k=2^{(2-\log_23)2^k-k-2}\quad\Rightarrow\quad x_k=\frac{2^{2^{k+1}}}{2^{k+2}3^{2^k}}.
$$
Going back to $T(n)$, this gives 
$$
T(n)=\frac{4^{n-1}}{n3^n}.
$$